# java PECS List<? super T> dest and List<T> dest difference?

Tags: java

```
public static <T> void copy1(List<? extends T> src, List<? super T> dest) {
    for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
        dest.add(src.get(i));
    }
}

public static <T> void copy2(List<? extends T> src, List<T> dest) {
    for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
        dest.add(src.get(i));
    }
}
```

top 2 method both can implements PECS Effect，but what difference ??

thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

PECS -> Producer Extends Consumer Super

- ? extends T -> from the list perspective, it acts as a producer to others. You can get items from it (list produces), but you can’t insert into it. In Java world, it is called covariance.
- ? super T-->This is called consumer behavior, because, from the list perspective, it allows to add items to it (list consumes), but not useful in type-safety reading (producing). It's contravariance.
- T -->In here, we can insert any subtypes of T class into the list. And when we reading, it will return a type of T instance. This is called Invariance.

```
class  A{
    public int a;
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public int b;
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
public class GenericsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> invariant = new ArrayList<>();
        List<? extends A> covariant = new ArrayList<>();
        List<? super A> contravariant = new ArrayList<>();

        invariant.add(new B());
        invariant.get(0).getA();
        //Error as it expect the instance of A while reading
        // invariant.get(0).getB();

        //Error it will be used to read the values, we can't insert any values in it.
        // We will use this construct places like defining params to a function
        //covariant.add(new B());
        //covariant.add(new A());

        contravariant.add(new A());
        contravariant.add(new B());

        //Error, it will be used to write only
        //While reading, it will give you object type
        //contravariant.get(0).getA();

        //We can type-cast while reading
        A a = (A) contravariant.get(0);
        a.getA();
 copy1(invariant,invariant);
        copy2(invariant,invariant);

       //Error due to the dest param requires super of T
       // copy1(covariant,covariant);
        //Error due to the dest param requires  of T
        //copy2(covariant,covariant);

        copy1(covariant,contravariant);
        copy2(covariant,contravariant);
    }
 public static <T> void copy1(List<? extends T> src, List<? super T> dest) {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
            dest.add(src.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static <T> void copy2(List<? extends T> src, List<T> dest) {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
            dest.add(src.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

- Method 1 -- > public static  void copy1(List src, List dest)
  dest list will consume anything with type T and it's sub class. But, when we read it, it will return an instance with Object type which we need to be type caste.

  - Methpd 2---> public static  void copy2(List src, List dest)
    dest list will consume anything with type T and it's sub class. But, when we read it, it will return the instance of T

Reference --> https://medium.com/@isuru89/java-producer-extends-consumer-super-9fbb0e7dd268

PS:- Sorry for long answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example both methods are the same, because the type `T` is unbounded itself. Thus, both declarations just say that the `dst` parameter lists elements must be a superclass of `src` parameter lists elements, using `? super T` in copy1() does not add something new here.

PECS rule does not mean you must always put `extends` or `super` everywhere. Here is the complete example of PECS-compatible declaration from Item 32 of J. Bloch "Effective Java":

```
public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<? extends E> s1, Set<? extends E> s2);
```

No need to use a return type as `Set<? super E>` here.